# XAML Preventing certain values of a Combo Box from being selected

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I require certain values of a Combo Box prevented from being selected by the user, when specific values are chosen in the first ComboBox, I have two comboboxes like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="jobTypeComboBox"      SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" Margin="10,66,209,461" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" AllowDrop="True" PlaceholderText="job type" Background="Black" Foreground="#FFFDFDFD">
        <x:String>Repair</x:String>
        <x:String>Replace</x:String>
        <x:String>Special</x:String>
        <x:String>Commercial</x:String>
        <x:String>Plexi</x:String>
        <x:String>Other</x:String>
</ComboBox>
<ComboBox x:Name="glassTypeComboBox" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" Margin="10,109,209,410" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" AllowDrop="True" PlaceholderText="glass type" Background="Black">
        <x:String>Windscreen</x:String>
        <x:String>Rearscreen</x:String>
        <x:String>Side Glass</x:String>
        <x:String>Mirror</x:String>
        <x:String>Building Glass</x:String>
        <x:String>Other</x:String>
</ComboBox>
```

If I select 'Repair' on the first combobox the second combobox cant contain any value other than 'windscreen' or 'rear screen' I am new to XAML and am unsure what way I would go about denying the user from selecting certain values on this combo box

EDIT:

```
  private void jobTypeComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var glassType in glassTypeComboBox.Items)
        {
            ComboBoxItem cbi = glassType as ComboBoxItem;
            cbi.IsEnabled = true; // always default to enabled.
            if (jobTypeComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Repair")
            {
                if ((cbi.Content.ToString() != "Windscreen") && (cbi.Content.ToString() != "Rearscreen"))
                {
                    cbi.IsEnabled = false;
                }

            }
            if (jobTypeComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Replace")
            {
                //More conditions here
            }
        }
    }
```

Is what I'm using to try remove/disable the values I dont want (thanks to Lynn Crumbling) for the idea/help! Just cant get it to read the if condition here:

```
if (jobTypeComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Repair")
```

I've also tried:

```
if (this.jobTypeComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Repair")
```

and  Lynn's initial suggestion with quite a few instances of this.

It just skips it during debugging even when it is selected. Any extra advice would be awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your entries in the combobox to actual ComboBoxItem controls:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="jobTypeComboBox"  
        SelectionChanged="jobTypeComboBox_SelectionChanged" ...more stuff...>
    <sys:String>Repair</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Replace</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Special</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Commercial</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Plexi</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Other</sys:String>
</ComboBox>
<ComboBox x:Name="glassTypeComboBox" 
      SelectionChanged="glassTypeComboBox_SelectionChanged"  ...more stuff...>
    <ComboBoxItem>Windscreen</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Rearscreen</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Side Glass</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Mirror</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Building Glass</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Other</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

You can wire up your `jobTypeComboBox_SelectionChanged` event to modify the enabled ComboBoxItems of your choosing:

```
private void jobTypeComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, 
           System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var glassType in this.glassTypeComboBox.Items)
    {
        ComboBoxItem cbi = glassType as ComboBoxItem;
        cbi.IsEnabled = true; // always default to enabled.
        if (this.jobTypeComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Repair")
        {
            if ((cbi.Content.ToString() != "Windscreen") && 
                       (cbi.Content.ToString() != "Rearscreen"))
            {
                cbi.IsEnabled = false;
            }
        }
        if (this.jobTypeComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Replace")
        {
            // Add more conditions... you get the idea...
        }
    }
}
```

This is just a small snippet, specifically looking to disable those items. You'll probably want a lot more conditions.

Side note: ever consider using an MVVM approach along with Databinding? It's sooooo powerful.

Comment: Hey thanks heaps for that! This looks promising... and Im sorry Im not familiar with MVVM

Comment: Hey there, upon implementing this and testing it, it does not work, when I debugged it it skipped through
         if (this.jobTypeComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString() == "Repair")
        {
Even though I did have repair selected, I tried a few things but I couldnt get it working. Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Not sure - it works fine for me. I put it under a debugger to verify.

Comment: Did you use sys:String for the jobTypeComboBox? I tried with both ComboBoxItem and sys:String

Comment: Yes - I left that combo as-is. I only changed the type for the entries in the glassTypeComboBox combo.

Comment: You said it skipped over `this.jobTypeComboBox.SelectedValue` ... if you put a breakpoint there, what is that value set to (when one is selected)?

Comment: Awesome. That fixed it, I had set both comboboxes to <ComboBoxItem>s rather than having the first as strings so it was not picking it up, and the value was "", strange - but it works setting them as x:String! Thanks again Lynn

Answer (score 0):

Try this for deleting items from ComboBox and don't forget to save all jobTypeComboBox items to restore them if job type changed. It's just only an idea. Specialize it as you want.

```
 if (jobTypeComboBox.Text == "Repair")
       for (int i = 2; i < jobTypeComboBox.Items.Count; i++)
          glassTypeComboBox.RemoveAt(i);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try!

Comment: Hmm I could see where this would work well, but ideally I would like the values to still be there, just not selectable by the user